# How to setup parametrized next routing w/o server-side rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I am trying to set up the routing with my next.js configuration. Whatever I tried so far did not produce the intended results. This is becoming confusing and frustrating for me, any help will be appreciated.

Here is what I want:

- url goes to `/` => `/index.js`
- url goes to `/users/` => `/user/index.js`
- url goes to `/users/[user-id]` => `/user/user.js`

Here is what doesn't work:

```
module.exports = {
  target: "serverless",
  async rewrites() {
    return {
        afterFiles: [
          {
            source: "/users/",
            destination: "/users/"
          },
          {
            source: "/users/:path*",
            destination: "/users/:path*"
          },
          {
            source: "/:path*",
            destination: "/:path*"
          },
          {
            source: "/:else*",
            destination: "/"
          }
      ]
    };
  },
};
```

Comment: I also tried renaming `user.js` to `[userId].js` which felt a bit weird but it didn't work either.

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is, and why you're using the config to setup the routing. What does your `pages` folder look like? Next.js has a file-system based router, when a file is added to the `pages directory`, it's automatically available as a route. See https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction for details.